# Problems with scrollable in Jquery

Tags: jquery, scrollable

How could I arrive scrollable like this web site?
http://juliaariellephotography.com/

I know that they are use the “jQuery Tools”. But I have included the “Library of http://jquery.com/”. If I add the “jQuery Tools”, they would be clashing.

How could I ues the “Library of http://jquery.com/” that arrive scrollable?

Answer (score 0):

If you include the jQuery Tools plugin from the CDN used in the documentation then you will automatically get jQuery Core 1.6.4 as well:

> **Quick start**
>
> Insert the following line on your HTML page and you are
>   done!
>
> `<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>`
>
> This is the official jQuery Tools UI library and after the inclusion
>   you will have the following tools available:
>
> jQuery 1.6.4, Tabs, Tooltip, Scrollable, Overlay

*Source: http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html*

jQuery Tools requires jQuery Core to function (it's a plugin, well a set of plugins).

You can see from the source of the site that you linked-to that they are including the `http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/jquery.tools.min.j` file only (because it will include the jQuery Core as well).

Comment: @ChenYangHuang Well then you'll need to include the jQuery UI framework as well. Which I don't recommend, use either jQuery UI or jQuery Tools, not both.

Comment: @ChenYangHuang I think I get what you mean now, to find a scrolling plugin for jQuery, just search Google, there are tons.